# Prevent user to check check box randomly using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have following test checkboxes. A user can select any checkbox in any order. 
My question is how I can use javascript/jquery to prevent user to select checkbox randomly. 
I would like user to click first checkbox, than second and so on.

```
​1 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="1"  /><br />

2 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="2"  /><br /> 

3 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="3"  /><br /> 

 4 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="4"  />
```

I need help writing script that would only allows to check each of the chckboxx in order  - left to right.

Many Thanks in advance

**Re- Edited Question:**

```
   <div class="siblings">
     <ul>
       <table class="table table-bordered">
      <?php
       $count = 1;

      for($x=0; $x < 5; $x++){
       ?>
      <td>
     <div class="thumb">
      <label for="image <?php echo $count;?>"><img class="img" 
     src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
     <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image <?php echo $count;?>" 
      name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
      </td>

     <?php
     $count++;

     }

      ?>
     </table>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

num8er was faster than me, but along the same lines.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');

    for (let ix = 0; ix < checkboxes.length; ix++) {
        checkboxes[ix].addEventListener('change', toggle);
    }

    function toggle() {
        if (this.checked) {
            let el = this.nextElementSibling;
            while (el && el.tagName !== 'INPUT') {
                el = el.nextElementSibling;
            }
            if(el) el.disabled = false;
        } else {
            let el = this.nextElementSibling;
            while (el) {
                if (el.tagName === 'INPUT') {
                    el.disabled = true;
                    el.checked = false;
                }
                el = el.nextElementSibling;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="1"  /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="2" disabled /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="3" disabled /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="4" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling next ones and enabling if previous one is checked?

```js
$(function() {

  var sportsSelector = 'input[type="checkbox"][name="sports"]'; 
  $(sportsSelector)
    .on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this);

      if($this.is(':checked')) {
        $this
          .nextAll(sportsSelector)
          .first()
          .removeAttr('disabled')
          .removeAttr('checked');
        return;
      }

      $this
        .nextAll(sportsSelector)
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .removeAttr('checked');
    })
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .first().removeAttr('disabled');
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

1 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="1" /><br />

2 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="2" /><br /> 

3 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="3" /><br /> 

4 <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="4" />
```

Comment: num8er your answer is great and works. However, I've got another situation where checkbox are done through loop. How would apply similar javaScript to that. I have edited my original question. thank you @peter

Comment: @MuhammedIkram You should play with selectors. I've just gave You solution to Your question. Other stuff You can modify as You wish.